# Can't add script component because the script class cannot be found? what mean this is if all is ok?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Make Looping Background for 2d game and when i try to add the script "Can't add script component because the script class cannot be found"
my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class background : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(-1f,1f)][![enter image description here][1]][1]
    public float scrollSpeed = 0.5f;
    private float offset;
    private Material mat;
    void Start()
    {
        mat = GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        offset += (Time.deltaTime*scrollSpeed)/10f;
        mat.SetTextureOffset("_MainTex", new Vector2(offset, 0));
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please can you also show your UnityScript code, as you've only shown your C# code so far.

Comment: This question is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript]

Answer (score 0):

Try reimporting the script by copying the contents, making a new file, copying the contents into it and deleting the old one.

Comment: the same problem